# change the distance between axis points (scale) in only one axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple plot and I want to adjust the distance of two consecutive tick-points (major) on the x or y axis (the "step"-size used for the partition of the x, y domain). For example, in the code plot generated by the below code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y=x**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('tester.png')
```

I want to reduce the distance between the y-tick points by half (comparing to the distance appearing in the current plot).

I am aware that the default distance of tick points depends on the width,heigh of the figure object. So I want to get the maximum distance of y-ticks in the current plot and replace it by 1/2 (basically change the scale of the y-axis).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Locator in the matplotlib documentation

Comment: Locator customizes the position of the tickers ( I know how to use it). I want to allow bigger space between the consecutive ticks. I've found that the default maximum spacing in the axis depends on the figure's width or length. In this example I also want to increase/decrease the spacing in the x-axis by some proportion of the default size.

Comment: maybe is there any way to readjust the "Linear" scale of the axis?

Comment: Have a look at how bins is calculated for `AutoLocator`.  You basically want to change `nbins` so I would just do what they do: `nbins  = yourfactor *  ax.xaxis.get_tick_space()`.  If you need it to be responsive to interactive figure size changes, just make your own AutoLocator that redefines nibs the way you want.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8d179398f937a5c4b9763a4c54ff4059bb62c079/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L2160